# Override materialize style

Tags: css, sass, materialize

I'm using materialize CSS for my project, but I want to override the style of radio buttons to do give some ratings using the code from this [page](http://voidcanvas.com/make-simple-star-rating-by-radio-buttons-using-css/), so I can get this:

[image]

But instead I'm getting this:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<form id="ratingsForm">
    <div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-1" id="star-1" />
        <label class="star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-2" id="star-2" />
        <label class="star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-3" id="star-3" />
        <label class="star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-4" id="star-4" />
        <label class="star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-5" id="star-5" />
        <label class="star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the CSS to make the stars appear:

```
form .stars {
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked ~ span {
  width: 100%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked ~ span {
  width: 80%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked ~ span {
  width: 60%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked ~ span {
  width: 40%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked ~ span {
  width: 20%;
}
form .stars label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .stars label:hover ~ span {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}
form .stars label.star-5:hover ~ span {
  width: 100% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-4:hover ~ span {
  width: 80% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-3:hover ~ span {
  width: 60% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-2:hover ~ span {
  width: 40% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-1:hover ~ span {
  width: 20% !important;
}
form .stars span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 -60px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

What can I do to override the default style of radio buttons from Materialize CSS and leave only my stars?

Comment: Have you tried implementing .browser-default class? Not entirely sure if it works for anything other than ul and select.

Comment: @pandamakes I haven't, but there could be some default materialize styles for those elements too.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve your problem? Facing the same issue

Comment: @Dudis I did but modifying directly the source code to remove styling rules for all 'radio-buttons', check out my own answer below

Comment: I have tried browser-default with no luck. If i understand, the styling you suggested works, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sass, you can stop the form styling from being imported by editing /sass/components/forms/_forms.scss

```
@import 'input-fields';
// @import 'radio-buttons';
@import 'checkboxes';
@import 'switches';
@import 'select';
@import 'file-input';
@import 'range';
```

But keep in mind that none of your radio buttons will have the Material style.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all I wanted was to remove those circles the same way you want, but I id it easier with the follow CSS:

```
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label::before, [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label::after {
border: 0px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label::after, .with-gap[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
    z-index: -999;
}
```

You just need to include it after materialize or whatever CSS you have.